# Android with database connectivity in Sqlite 3

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm doing a schedule sms application in android using eclipse. The designing part is over. Now, i want to connect my fields and the date and time must stored in database. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to refer below database links. It may helps you lot.

1. [Android SQLiteDatabase](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
2. [SQLiteDatabase](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android)

By, the second link, it'll helps you lot. They've explained the database concepts briefly. And, also refer the example from there.

And, use [AlarmManager](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) for your scheduled application. Hope these helps you lot.